# Is there a way to mingle validations in jQuery and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-validate, validation

If we want to include jQuery Validation plugin as well as code igniter form_validation class at once we have to define the validation rules in both jQuery validation script as well as in CodeIgniter form_validation. Is there a way to mingle both in a single call. Like, I want to define the validation rules only once either in jQuery or CodeIgniter

jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation
CodeIgniter http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Process now:

```
//jQuery
$("#username").validate({
 debug: true
})
```

Code igniter:

```
//Code igniter
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
```

1) Load library in your controller.

```
$this->load->library('jquery_validation');
```

2) Set CodeIgniter standard validation rules ( The same rules format which has form_validtion library ).

```
$rules = array(
            array(
                 'field'   => 'username',
                 'label'   => 'Username',
                 'rules'   => 'required|min_length[2]'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'email',
                 'label'   => 'Email',
                 'rules'   => 'required|valid_email'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'url',
                 'label'   => 'URL',
                 'rules'   => 'required'
              )
       );
```

3) Set error messages.

```
$messages = array(
             'username'  => array( 'required'    => "Username is required",
                                   'min_length'  => "Please enter more then 2 char"
                                 ),

             'email'     => array( 'required'    => "Email is required",
                                   'valid_email' => "Please enter valid email"
                                 )
             );
```

4) Apply validation rules and messages to library.

```
$this->jquery_validation->set_rules($rules);
$this->jquery_validation->set_messages($messages);
```

5) Generate Javascript validation code.

```
// pass css selector for your form to run method

$validation_script = $this->jquery_validation->run('#registration_form');

// echo $validation_script in your <script> tag
```

This is the way to add jquery validation using code igniter validation definitions. My question is to get a validation library which uses this validation rule to both client side and server side validation.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery validation happens in the client.

Codeigniter validation happens on the server.

They're COMPLETELY independent of one another. If you set your rules up correctly, Codeigniter validation will only even happen if jQuery validation doesn't happen for some reason.

Comment: Thanks. But I knew this. Though there should be way to define the rules in a single touch. I have edited the question to make you understand.

Comment: I guess you could write a jQuery validation library that would use the CI validation rules to generate the correct jQuery validation rules...I don't know of a library that presently does that though.